# Kubernetes pods are getting failed with volume attach issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

We are seeing some of the pods getting failed while mounting/attaching volume to pods. this is happening intermittently and after bouncing kubelet service pods are able to reattach the volumes and succeeding. seeing the below error when pod get struck.

I created single PV and corresponding PVC to use volume mounts for pods:

Error:

**Warning  FailedMount  16m (x4 over 43m)    kubelet, ca1md-k8w03-02  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[workdir], unattached volumes=[default-token-pwvpc podmetadata docker-sock workdir]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount  7m32s (x5 over 41m)  kubelet, ca1md-k8w03-02  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[workdir], unattached volumes=[docker-sock workdir default-token-pwvpc podmetadata]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount  3m2s (x10 over 45m)  kubelet, ca1md-k8w03-02  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[workdir], unattached volumes=[podmetadata docker-sock workdir default-token-pwvpc]: timed out waiting for the condition
Warning  FailedMount  45s (x2 over 21m)    kubelet, ca1md-k8w03-02  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[workdir], unattached volumes=[workdir default-token-pwvpc podmetadata docker-sock]: timed out waiting for the condition**

Version:

```
Client Version: v1.17.2
Server Version: v1.17.2
```

Host OS:

```
Centos 7.7
```

CNI:

```
Weave
```

```html
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: StatefulSet
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2020-07-17T21:55:47Z"
    generation: 1
    labels:
      logicmonitor.com/collectorset: kubernetes-03
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:logicmonitor.com/collectorset: {}
        f:spec:
          f:podManagementPolicy: {}
          f:replicas: {}
          f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
          f:selector:
            f:matchLabels:
              .: {}
              f:logicmonitor.com/collectorset: {}
          f:template:
            f:metadata:
              f:labels:
                .: {}
                f:logicmonitor.com/collectorset: {}
              f:namespace: {}
            f:spec:
              f:affinity:
                .: {}
                f:podAntiAffinity:
                  .: {}
                  f:requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: {}
              f:containers:
                k:{"name":"collector"}:
                  .: {}
                  f:env:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"COLLECTOR_IDS"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"access_id"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:valueFrom:
                        .: {}
                        f:secretKeyRef:
                          .: {}
                          f:key: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:optional: {}
                    k:{"name":"access_key"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:valueFrom:
                        .: {}
                        f:secretKeyRef:
                          .: {}
                          f:key: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:optional: {}
                    k:{"name":"account"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:valueFrom:
                        .: {}
                        f:secretKeyRef:
                          .: {}
                          f:key: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:optional: {}
                    k:{"name":"collector_size"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"collector_version"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"kubernetes"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                    k:{"name":"use_ea"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:value: {}
                  f:image: {}
                  f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                  f:name: {}
                  f:resources:
                    .: {}
                    f:limits:
                      .: {}
                      f:memory: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                  f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
              f:dnsPolicy: {}
              f:restartPolicy: {}
              f:schedulerName: {}
              f:securityContext: {}
              f:serviceAccount: {}
              f:serviceAccountName: {}
              f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
          f:updateStrategy:
            f:type: {}
        f:status:
          f:replicas: {}
      manager: collectorset-controller
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-08-22T03:42:35Z"
    name: kubernetes-03
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "10831902"
    selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/statefulsets/kubernetes-03
    uid: 1296654b-77bc-4af8-9537-04f0a00bdd0c
  spec:
    podManagementPolicy: Parallel
    replicas: 1
    revisionHistoryLimit: 10
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        logicmonitor.com/collectorset: kubernetes-03
    serviceName: ""
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          logicmonitor.com/collectorset: kubernetes-03
        namespace: default
      spec:
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  logicmonitor.com/collectorset: kubernetes-03
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: account
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: account
                name: collectorset-controller
                optional: false
          - name: access_id
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: accessID
                name: collectorset-controller
                optional: false
          - name: access_key
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: accessKey
                name: collectorset-controller
                optional: false
          - name: kubernetes
            value: "true"
          - name: collector_size
            value: small
          - name: collector_version
            value: "0"
          - name: use_ea
            value: "false"
          - name: COLLECTOR_IDS
            value: "205"
          image: logicmonitor/collector:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: collector
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 2Gi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: {}
        serviceAccount: collector
        serviceAccountName: collector
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    updateStrategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  status:
    collisionCount: 0
    currentReplicas: 1
    currentRevision: kubernetes-03-655b46ff69
    observedGeneration: 1
    readyReplicas: 1
    replicas: 1
    updateRevision: kubernetes-03-655b46ff69
    updatedReplicas: 1
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

```html
kubectl get pv -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    annotations:
      pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    creationTimestamp: "2020-07-10T00:21:49Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
    labels:
      type: local
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:spec:
          f:accessModes: {}
          f:capacity:
            .: {}
            f:storage: {}
          f:nfs:
            .: {}
            f:path: {}
            f:server: {}
          f:persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: {}
          f:storageClassName: {}
          f:volumeMode: {}
      manager: kubectl
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-07-10T00:21:49Z"
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: {}
        f:spec:
          f:claimRef:
            .: {}
            f:apiVersion: {}
            f:kind: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:namespace: {}
            f:resourceVersion: {}
            f:uid: {}
        f:status:
          f:phase: {}
      manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-07-10T00:21:52Z"
    name: pv-modeldata
    resourceVersion: "15764"
    selfLink: /api/v1/persistentvolumes/pv-data
    uid: 68521e84-0aa9-4643-a047-441a61451599
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    capacity:
      storage: 5999Gi
    claimRef:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      name: pvc-modeldata
      namespace: default
      resourceVersion: "15762"
      uid: e4a1309e-339d-4ed5-8fe1-9ed32f779ea7
    nfs:
      path: /k8fs03
      server: kubemaster01.rms.com
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    storageClassName: manual
    volumeMode: Filesystem
  status:
    phase: Bound
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""


# kubectl get pvc -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
      pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    creationTimestamp: "2020-07-10T00:21:52Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
    managedFields:
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: {}
            f:pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: {}
        f:spec:
          f:volumeName: {}
        f:status:
          f:accessModes: {}
          f:capacity:
            .: {}
            f:storage: {}
          f:phase: {}
      manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-07-10T00:21:52Z"
    - apiVersion: v1
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:spec:
          f:accessModes: {}
          f:resources:
            f:requests:
              .: {}
              f:storage: {}
          f:storageClassName: {}
          f:volumeMode: {}
      manager: kubectl
      operation: Update
      time: "2020-07-10T00:21:52Z"
    name: pvc-modeldata
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "15766"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/pvc-data
    uid: e4a1309e-339d-4ed5-8fe1-9ed32f779ea7
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 5999Gi
    storageClassName: manual
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    volumeName: pv-data
  status:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    capacity:
      storage: 5999Gi
    phase: Bound
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""

# kubectl get sc -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items: []
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Thanks,
Chittu

Comment: Could you share details of your pod ```kubectl describe pod <<podname>> -n <<namespacename>>``` ? and also list your PV & PVCs please?

Comment: after bouncing kubelet pod started running fine and finished. I dont have pod log.[root@knode1 ~]# kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pv-data   5999Gi     RWX            Retain           Bound    default/pvc-data   manual                  45d

NAME                                  STATUS   VOLUME         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/pvc-modeldata   Bound    pv-data   5999Gi     RWX            manual         45d

Comment: Can you provide more details: `kubectl get sts -o yaml`, `kubectl get pv -o yaml`, `kubectl get pvc -o yaml`, `kubectl get sc -o yaml`, `kubectl describe pending_pod` (provide output from events as stackoveflow code). Also in volume you are using `RWX` mode which is not supported by default so please provide more details about config, deployment yamls and configuration.

Comment: Just uploaded the info, Please let me know if I need to tweak anything. thanks in advance @acid_fuji

Comment: Thx. Can you test it with ReadWriteOnce mode setup up?

Comment: @thomas, our workflow spins pods across multiple worker nodes and when we have ReadWriteOnce set, thats creates problem I believe. I tried it but somehow I am unable to set ReadWriteOnce permisssions on PVC.